# Is the work done by gravity equal to the work done against friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work, friction

If there is a block on a ramp, and it slides to the bottom (with friction), then is the work done by gravity always equal to the work done against friction?

Comment: Do you mean "work done by friction"? Forces do work. What does "work done against friction" mean?

Comment: Since the displacement is opposite the force, wouldn't it be considered work done against friction?

Comment: I think the usual way to describe it is "the work done by friction is negative". The phrase "work done against friction" makes it sound like you are focusing on other things doing the work, but here you really do mean "the work done by friction". It is much less confusing to say "work done by the force" in all cases.

Comment: @BioPhysicist, It is usual to talk of work done against friction. It is already clear that the work is done by gravity, and we are simply dividing it into parts, as described by Dale. The idea of work being done by friction, whether positive or negative, is bizarre, because friction does not cause movement (only opposes it), so friction cannot do work.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis The work done by a force $\mathbf F$ is $\int\mathbf F\cdot\text d\mathbf x$, so both gravity and friction do work here. Unless you are saying $\int\mathbf F\cdot\text d\mathbf x=0$ here for friction? What about an object sliding on a flat surface and coming to rest due to friction. You would say there is no force doing work here? What is doing the "work against friction" in that scenario? Just because work is negative doesn't mean it is nonexistent or there is work "against" it.

Comment: @BioPhysicist, I agree that is an example showing that friction does negative work. Probably that is why it is more usual to talk of work done against friction.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis In both my example and this one friction does negative work. It's not unique to the example I gave. The phrase "work done against friction" is confusing because It sounds like you are talking about the work done by a another force that is opposing friction. This is problematic when you actually do mean to talk about the work done *by* friction (like the OP does here), and/or when there is only friction doing work where there isn't anything against friction at all. Why confuse students with two terminologies when one is sufficient and not subjective?

Comment: @BioPhysicist, This was my point. The terminology work against friction is completely clear and has been well established since long before I first studied mechanics almost forty years ago. The idea of a force doing negative work is intrinsically confusing, and I don't recall ever hearing it before.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I guess physics education is different then. I've seen plenty examples where $\int F\,\text dx$ is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The work done by gravity is equal to the work done against friction plus the change in the kinetic energy.

Comment: Technically $W_\text{grav}+W_\text{fric}=\Delta K$, not $W_\text{grav}=W_\text{fric}+\Delta K$

Comment: Oops, yes. A “by” vs “against” error. Now fixed, thanks!

Comment: I have asked for clarification from the OP, but IMO "work done against..." doesn't make sense.

Comment: It seems fine to me. In context Julia meant “work done against X” = -“work done by X”.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what they mean.

Comment: Just a question, why is the change in kinetic energy rather than the change in potential energy being used to calculate the work? Could the change in potential energy be used to calculate this?

Comment: The change in gravitational potential energy is the same thing as the work done by gravity. You can call it by either name.

Comment: @Julia $W_\text{grav}=-\Delta U_\text{grav}$, which is true for all conservative forces

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Julia Don't forget to up vote all useful answers and to select one answer as the accepted answer if it sufficiently answers your question.